# Using NSNotifications to pass variables between View Controllers

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass an integer variable between two view controllers using NSNotifications, however despite now having figured out how to detect a notification sent by another view controller, I still haven't figured out how to actually pass a variable within this notification.

This is the code I have in the view controller I am sending the variable from:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent: Int) {
    var colourSelected = row
    println(colourSelected)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("changeColor:", object: colourSelected)
}
```

And this is the code within the viewDidLoad of the ViewController that I am sending the variable to:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "incomingNotification", name: "changeColor:", object: nil)
```

This is the function that should be receiving the variable:

```
func incomingNotification() {

if colourSelected == 0 {
println(0)
} else if colourSelected == 1 {
println(1) }

...

}
```

I am just getting an error saying that colourSelected is an unresolved identifier.

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

```
//Sent notification 

let dictionary = ["key":"value"]    
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("passDataInView", object: nil, userInfo: dictionary)

 //Receive  notification 

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
   selector:"myMethod:", name: "passDataInView", object: nil)

 //Receive  notification method

   func myMethod(notification: NSNotification){

   labelName.text = notification.userInfo!["key"]

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 //Sent notification 
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("passDataInView", object: nil, userInfo: passedURObject(dictionary,array,int))

 //Receive  notification 
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "dataReceived", name: "passDataInView", object: getURObject(dictionary,array,int))

 //Receive  notification method
   func dataReceived(notification: NSNotification){
    //do your stuff here...
    }
```

Comment: So I tried 'NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("colourSelectedPass", object: nil, userInfo: colourSelected)

Comment: userinfo,is a dictionary.so ur object passed as a dictionary.dictionary into set ur int value.

Comment: Huh is right.  There should be some reasonable grammar standard for posts here.